# Removing proxy for apt

Tags: networking, apt, proxy

I am having trouble removing proxy from apt. I recently came home from my institute where they used proxy to access internet. I had set up apt proxy using `etc/apt/apt.conf` file. I also had set the environment variables for proxies, and edited the proxy settings. Now that I have removed the lines from `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and removed the network proxy settings, I still cannot install apps using apt. Firefox runs fine without any hiccups.

I tried `unset`ing the proxy variables but after reboot they still persist.

I am using Ubuntu Mate 18.04

The output of `set | grep -i proxy` is :

```
FTP_PROXY=http://172.16.2.30:8080/
HTTPS_PROXY=https://172.16.2.30:8080/
HTTP_PROXY=http://172.16.2.30:8080/
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1
ftp_proxy=http://172.16.2.30:8080/
http_proxy=http://172.16.2.30:8080/
https_proxy=https://172.16.2.30:8080/
no_proxy=127.0.0.0/8,::1,10.0.0.0/8
```

The Proxy settings look like this:

[image]

How can I remove the proxy settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured the proxy variables are either stored in `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/environment`. I had edited the `/etc/environment` file before and I forgot that. I grepped each file for proxy and I the lines were in `etc/environment`.

I removed those lines and now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this by editing and hashing out proxy details under the file `90curtin-aptproxy` under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`

Comment: I dont have any such file

Comment: found mine in /etc/apt/apt.conf

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problems as you did. The error that showed was

> ```
> E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf:4: Block starts with no name
> ```

So I then used `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` and deleted text related to proxy in it, leaving only the following:

> ```
> DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};
> ```

Doing so solved the issue for me

Comment: I didn't notice that you already did that, but i helped me.

Answer (score 0):

list the proxy settings through `env | grep -i proxy`

the output for the following was

```
HTTP_PROXY=localhost:9191
FTP_PROXY=localhost:9191
https_proxy=localhost:9191
.....
```

I tried the following command to empty those variables
export `HTTP_PROXY=` with all the variables done, the proxy settings are back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find my proxy configured in

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf
```

I found it by

```
grep -R the.proxy.from.my.error.messsage /etc/*
```

I just commented it out